# Can't get Fragment Manager in my Activity that extends YouTubeBaseActivity

Tags: java, android, supportfragmentmanager

So my app has a Youtube Player view in the main activity, my initial intention was to add a Tablayout with it's ViewPager, however, when coding I realised **i couldn't get Support Fragment manager** for my Adapter.

**Header of my class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
            YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {
```

Comment: `YouTubeBasicActivity` extends `Activity`, not the Jetpack `FragmentActivity`, so you cannot use Jetpack fragments with it. You might want to consider [using `YouTubePlayerView`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) directly in activities and fragments that you control.

Comment: yeah, thanks. It seems ill have to redesign my app